# Laravel | Redirigir despues de login según valor en tabla

Tags: php, laravel, blade

Mi duda es la siguiente, luego de hacer login, debo verificar si el usuario tiene foto, en caso de tenerla pues va directo a su perfil y si no, va a la pagina para que elija una foto.

TABLAS:

USERS: id, name, email, password

VENDEDORES: id, nombre, foto

Es decir, si el campo "foto" de mi tabla VENDEDORES no tiene una ruta de imagen registrada haga un redirect a la vista select_foto.blade.php, caso contrario entonces que el redirect vaya a profile.blade.php.

Cual archivo relacionado a la autenticación debo modificar para redirigir?

En mi caso este proyecto ya esta desarrollado. Y les muestro:

RedirectIfAuthenticated.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
     {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
    }
```

RouteServiceProvider.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
/**
 * This namespace is applied to your controller routes.
 *
 * In addition, it is set as the URL generator's root namespace.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';

/**
 * The path to the "home" route for your application.
 *
 * @var string
 */
public const HOME = '/';
public const PROFILE = '/perfil';
```

Acá hay un poco más de código pero creo que es irrelevante.

Continuo con:
LoginController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use App;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
use AuthenticatesUsers;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after login.
 *
 * @var string
 */

protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::PROFILE;



@return void

@return string

public function username()
{
    $login = request()->input('id_user');
    if($login){ 
        return 'id_user';
    }else{
        return 'username';
    }
}

public function login_username()
{
    $users = App\User::all();
    return view('auth/login-username',compact('users'));
}

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
}
}
```

Comment: ¿Como se relaciona el usuario con el vendedor?

Comment: Ese middleware a que rutas está aplicado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que introducir la lógica que quieres en la clase RedirectIfAuthenticated, el método handle es el que maneja el redireccionado despues del login.

```
class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
     {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {

            if(Si tiene foto) { 
              // Query a la BD para comprobar si tiene foto
                return redirect('profile');

            } else {
              // Si no tiene foto
              return redirect('select_foto');
        }


        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```